# Equivalents of Google Colab with more RAM

Tags: google-colaboratory

Im currently working on a project creating simulations from defined models. Most of the testing on down-sized models has taken place in google colab to make use of the GPU accelerator option. However, when up-scaling to the full sized models I now exceed the maximum RAM for google colab. Is there an equivalent service which allows for 25GB RAM rather than 12GB. Access to GPU acceleration is still essential

Note: I am outside the US so Google Colab Pro is not an option